# Insert into table using for loop index

Tags: sql, oracle

trying to insert data into table using for loop, for table customer i have data into 3 partition.

here is the code

```
begin
FOR var_1 in 1 .. 3
LOOP
INSERT into tmp_table
(
        SELECT cust_no FROM customer PARTITION (customer_PR$var_1)
        WHERE city='ba' AND first_name='john'
        AND salary=1000);
commit;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I get result as

```
Error report -
ORA-02149: Specified partition does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 4
02149. 00000 -  "Specified partition does not exist"
*Cause:    Partition not found for the object.
*Action:   Retry with correct partition name.
```

but when I run normally(for partition 1),

```
SELECT cust_no FROM customer PARTITION (customer_PR1);
```

I get expected output.

Comment: $ is not the way to reference variables in PL/SQL

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO then what should be used? pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need dynamic SQL here to achieve your goal -

```
Declare
       sql_text varchar2(500);
begin
     FOR var_1 in 1 .. 3
     LOOP
         sql_text := 'INSERT into tmp_table
                      (SELECT cust_no FROM customer PARTITION (customer_PR' || var_1 || ')
                        WHERE city=''ba'' AND first_name=''john''
                          AND salary=1000)';
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_text;
         COMMIT;
     END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 3 different queries, just use `PARTITION()` clause properly - specify all the partition needed:

```sql
    INSERT into tmp_table
        SELECT cust_no 
        FROM customer PARTITION (customer_PR1,customer_PR3,customer_PR3)
        WHERE city='ba' AND first_name='john'
        AND salary=1000;
```

And if you really need dynamic sql, you can concatenate your query:

```
begin
FOR var_1 in 1 .. 3
LOOP
  execute immediate q'[
    INSERT into tmp_table
        SELECT cust_no FROM customer PARTITION (customer_PR]'||var_1||q'[
        WHERE city='ba' AND first_name='john'
        AND salary=1000)
        ]';
  commit;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

or depending on your partitioning rules, you can use `partition for` clause:

```
begin
FOR partitioning_key in {your_partitioning keys}
LOOP
INSERT into tmp_table
(
        SELECT cust_no FROM customer PARTITION FOR (partitioning_key)
        WHERE city='ba' AND first_name='john'
        AND salary=1000);
commit;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-partitioning.html

Comment: for 2nd  answer  how do we define range for {your_partitioning keys}?

Comment: @roger I don't know your partitioning scheme, please provide full DDL of your table and I will show

Comment: let me check that....and for answer one, it would be helpful if you explain you answer.

Comment: @Roger I've just found out after your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67167774/spool-to-csv-file-using-for-loop/67171638#67171638 that you don't need dynamic query at all. Just specify all partitions in `PARTITION` clause