# spool to .csv file using for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

need to spool output into .csv file using loop, fyi...I have data in 4 diff partition.

but no sure how to  proceed.

code be like.

```
begin
FOR var_1 in 1 .. 4
LOOP
set linesize 1000
set feedback off
set underline off
spool C:\Users\file.csv replace
        SELECT cust_no FROM customer PARTITION (customer_PR'||var_1||')
        WHERE city='ba' AND first_name='john'
        AND salary=1000;
spool off;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

result:-

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

not sure if I am spooling properly, also please check the index variable of for loop in  used correctly in my select statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need 4 different queries, just list all your partitions in the query:

```sql
set linesize 1000
set feedback off
set underline off
spool C:\Users\file.csv replace
SELECT cust_no FROM customer PARTITION (customer_PR1, customer_PR2, customer_PR3, customer_PR4)
        WHERE city='ba' AND first_name='john'
        AND salary=1000;
spool off;
```

Answer (score 2):

Spool is a SQL*Plus command and PL/SQL doesn't "understand" it. You'd rather switch to `UTL_FILE` package, if it has to be PL/SQL.

Though, if that's the only code you have, I'd suggest you to simply use 4 separate `SELECT` statements, each using its own partition, and spool the result into a CSV file.

If you did that, you'd be done HOURS ago.

Comment: could you please show how can I used UTL_FILE here..?

Answer (score 1):

`spool` is a SQL*Plus command which might be combined with an embedded PL/SQL code containing a cursor such as `SYS_REFCURSOR` with a dynamic SQL as

```
rec=$(sqlplus -S /nolog << EOF
 conn hr/hr
 whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
 SET LINESIZE 1000
 SET FEEDBACK OFF
 SET UNDERLINE OFF
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 SPOOL file.csv REPLACE
 DECLARE
  v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql    VARCHAR2(32767); 
  cust     customer.cust_no%TYPE;
 BEGIN
  FOR var_1 in 1..4 
  LOOP
    v_sql := 
     'SELECT cust_no
        FROM customer PARTITION(customer_pr'||var_1||')
       WHERE city = :ct
         AND first_name = :fn
         AND salary = :sl';           
    OPEN v_cursor FOR v_sql USING 'ba','john',1000; 
    LOOP
      FETCH v_cursor INTO cust;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cust);
      EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;  
  CLOSE v_cursor;
 END;
 /
 SPOOL OFF
EOF
)
```